# Return a List<int> from List<T> with an integer property?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

The end result is I want to use `.Where(t => someIntList.Contains(t.ID)).ToList()`. I'm struggling to create `someIntList`.

What I have so far: `List<Person> people = people.Where(p => p.isActive).ToList()`. How do I return just a `List<int>` of the `p.ID` property?

Or is there another way to do Contains (without writing a Comparer class as I already have one used for another purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, producing the `List<int>` is easy, using [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) to perform the projection:

```
List<int> activeIds = people.Where(p => p.IsActive)
                            .Select(p => p.ID)
                            .ToList();
```

However, rather than do that and then use `Contains`, I would perform a join:

```
var activePeople = people.Where(p => p.IsActive);
var query = from person in otherList
            join activePeople on person.ID equals activePeople.ID
            select person;
```

Or create a `HashSet<int>` instead of a `List<int>`, so that the `Contains` check is more efficient:

```
var activeIds = new HashSet<int>(people.Where(p => p.IsActive)
                                       .Select(p => p.ID));
var query = otherList.Where(t => activeIds.Contains(t.ID))
                     .ToList();
```

Both of these will give O(M + N) complexity for finding all matches, rather than O(M * N) that constructing a list and then using *that* for the `Contains` check would do.

Of course, that's assuming the `Contains` check is going to be done in-process. If this is *actually* going to be used in a LINQ to SQL query, then it *could* be that passing in a `List<int>` is fine - or it *could* be that the join allows you to do it all in the database. We really need more context to give you good advice - but *don't* just stop at "this is how I can build a `List<T>`, therefore I'm done."

Comment: Thanks, given me something to think about. The code is more complex than the example which I tried to simply.

Comment: @IgorK: The more information you can give, the more useful our answers can be. We can't *really* tell whether you need a `List<T>` , or whether that's just what you originally thought of.

Comment: Can you please explain how to create the HashSet<int>? I don't see how you can just pass in an IENumerable as a parameter?

Comment: @IgorK: I'd missed the `Select` call - oops. But then I'm just calling the constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet: I deleted my answer since I'd rather see him use the more efficient solution than the 'quick-and-dirty' solution.

Comment: I've done some testing with the Stopwatch. Using Contains(), the code executes in 661 milliseconds. Using Contains() with the HashSet runs in 5 milliseconds. Thanks - I'm very happy with that.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to perform a group join?  It would remove duplicates and would possibly be more efficient.

Comment: @RiskyMartin: Yes, it would reduce duplicates - but it would also mean you'd have to filter out empty groups. To be honest if these are really IDs, I'd *expect* there not to be any duplicates... but we can't really say without trying it.